# What is the translation for this song and maybe the name of the song

Tags: translation, lyrics

My great grandmother turned 100 today and received a gift with parts of a German song mostly with quacking. But the little lyrics that I could find, my mom can't translate them either (she lived in Germany for 10 years.) can you please give me any information?

[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: This "quak" is imho just babble. "Schön ist das Kon" means "The Kon is beautiful", but I have no idea what could be a Kon. I don't think that your question is answerable, due to the too few information.

Comment: I guess it is a song about a frog concert and probaly that cut off sentence reads "schön ist das Konzert" (the concert is beautiful), but I could not find a matching song for this.

Comment: We don’t do translations here, but I still wonder why you didn’t include the text that you would like to have translated.

Comment: Are there any further information printed on the sheets, such as the publisher, year of publication or similar?

Comment: Why don't you take a photograph of the entire sheet? One could at least sing the song then. Quak.

Comment: Maybe this is an intonation: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=dON6pb34k7o - I'm not well enough in reading notes to compare the melody.

Comment: @userunknown May _quaks_, but I didn't hear the "_rega, reg_" from the first image...

Comment: @Arsak @ Christian Geiselmann I only had what I pictured. It wasn't full sheets. Someone had used the music sheets, cut up, as decoration for this artistic journal. There was just these bits and pieces.

Comment: I’m voting to keep this question **open**, since our position on whether lyric identification is not very clear ([no](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/734/do-we-want-to-allow-story-identification-questions) vs [maybe](https://german.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1409/are-what-lyric-text-questions-on-topic/1412#1412) (as per the upvoted questions).

Comment: @Kyoumimasu: this paper used as wrapping paper limits the "full qualified specs". Maybe you can disassemble it a bit further? Because there are many foldings and "glued" pages - flatten these out would give more context etc. pp.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Short answer:
I think this is a song for 4 year old children, named *Froschkonzert (frog concert)*

---

long answer:

**Text**

- > Schön ist das Kon... *(Konzert?)*
  >   The kon *(concert?)* is beautiful

"Quak" is not a German word, but it is the stem of the verb *quaken (engl: to quack).* I guess, that this stem of a verb is used for onomatopoetic reasons, i.e. to simulate the quacking sound of frogs.

Neither "rega" nor "reg" are German words or stems of German words. But I guess that those *words* are also used to immitate frog-sounds.

The fragment "-sche" is the last syllable of about 800 different German words. It is impossible to tell the whole word, and so it is not possible to offer any translation. (Some words that end in *-sche* are: Tasche = bag, Flasche = bottle, Bursche = fellow, Wäsche = laundry, Fische = fish, Dusche = shower etc.)

---

**Instructions**

- > Weiter steigern bis zur Grenze des Ausführbaren
  >   Continue to increase up to the limit of executable
- > lang
  >   long

The other instructions are not German but musical standard (p = piano = silent, gliss = glissando = slide the pitch)

---

The song has a very simple melody. I don't know it, but I guess it is written for preschool children. Because I guess it is a about a concert, and because of all the quacking I would call it *Froschkonzert (frog concert)*. And in fact there is a song for 4 year old children with this name, but i couldn't find out, if your score sheet really is this song.

Comment: The song seems to be for four voices. Not sure, if  four year olds can do this already...

Comment: Thank you! This makes the most sense! My mom said that works!

Comment: @Arsak someone mentioned this video which probably could be it: https://youtu.be/dON6pb34k7o. There was a few different kid songs about frogs but this was the only one that said 'quak' a lot and seemed like there were many layers. I'm content with this answer since I at least know the song is a children's tune about frogs which I didn't know before and I know new vocab!